# Feed java program scanner(system.in) instructions with text files

Tags: java, testing, text, input, java.util.scanner

I have a program that I want to run test cases on, I'm supposed to automate iterating through all the test cases using the Terminal. My problem is that I have already written the program to take in input using the Scanner(System.in) command (Through the keyboard).

Is there a way to feed my program the input using text files instead of keyboard *without* changing my code? [Eg: using a specific terminal command that would extract text from a file and give it back to the program when prompted for keyboard entry]

Many thanks

======================
Note: I have multiple inputs not just one. If I change the standard input stream(?) to the text file, how do I control the extraction so that every line is one "answer"?

Comment: *without changing my code*

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do. Please provide an example run with example input / output.